# Implementation of timeout in LDAP

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap, ldapconnection

I have been handling an application in which we are using **LDAP** to fetch user details. Sometimes it will take more time to fetch user details. I want to implement **time out** on methods that fetch details so that we can avoid hanging transactions in server in worst case.

Here we are using `LdapUtil` class in which we have configured `LdapTemplate` class to fetch the required details.

**How can we implement timeout on LDAP methods?**
(In this case `ldapTemplate.search(...)` methods)

```
public class LdapUtil {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "ldapTemplateApp")
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    public Set < ProductGroup > findProducts(String UserId) {
        final Set < ProductGroup > products = newHashSet();
        // Lookup the user         
        String usrFilter = String.format(USERID_FILTER, globalUserId);

        ldapTemplate.search("ou=Members", usrFilter, // note this line
        new NameClassPairCallbackHandler() {

            public void handleNameClassPair(NameClassPair nameClassPair) {
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) nameClassPair;
                String user = result.getNameInNamespace();

                String GrpFilter = String.format(GROUP_FILTER, user);

                List < String > zonePrefixes = ldapTemplate.search("Zones", GrpFilter, // note this line
                new AttributesMapper() {
                    public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
                        return substringBeforeLast((String) attributes.get("cn").get(), "-") + "-";
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        products.remove(null);
        return newHashSet(products);
    }
}
```

We have one **LDAP.xml** in which ldapTemplete is configured

```
<beans xmlns="------">
<!-- LDAP -->
<bean id="contextSourceApp" class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.factory.PoolingContextSource">
<property name="contextSource" ref="contextSourceTargetApp" />
<property name="dirContextValidator">
<bean id="dirContextValidator"   
class="org.springframework.ldap.pool.validation.DefaultDirContextValidator"/>
</property>         
<property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="contextSourceTargetApp" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
    <property name="base" value="${ldap.base.}" />
    <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
    <property name="pooled" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplateApp" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSourceApp" />
</bean>
```

I have few queries:

1. **How can we implement the TIMEOUT for LDAP methods and how to configure it?**(In which class of LDAP framework timeout settings will be there)
2. **Is there any way to configure them in xml file i.e. LDAP.xml(in this case)?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution.
I have added the following property in my ldap.xml file. So far it worked for me.

```
<bean id="contextSourceTargetApp" 
      class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="5000" />          
        </map>  
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please post any other solution if you have any idea about LDAP timeout implementation.

Answer (score 3):

For `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` the solution with ldap.xml file did not work for me. Instead I added a `jndi.properties` file to the classpath with the following content:

```
com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout=500
```